# Passing object array from jsp to java servlet using JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp, servlets

the following codes are what i'm trying to figure out.Hope you guys can help me !

jsp :

```
<input name="test" type="text" /><br/>
<input name="test" type="text" /><br/>
<input name="test" type="text" /><br/>
<input id="query" type="button" value="query" onClick="doajax()"/>
```

js  :

```
function doajax(){
    var dataSet = $("input[type='text'][name='test']").serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/testJson",
            dataType: "json",
            data:dataSet,
            error:function(){   
                alert("error occured!!!");   
            },
            success:function(data){
                alert("success");
            }  
    });
}
```

* [Update] ***

I'm using Struts 2.0.
I usually get the parameters by " get and set " instead of `request.getParameters()`.

How can i get the `dataSet` in Java Servlet ?

Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataSet` is a regular `POST` parameter, so get it the regular way.

Then use a JSON library like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to transform the JSON to an object. You'll need to define the structure as a class, however. So, if you have a `DataSet` class that maps exactly to the json you sent, you can fill it with (Jackson):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DataSet object = mapper.readValue(dataSet, DataSet.class);
```

Then if you want to send some JSON ase response, either convert the response data and write it to the `response.getWriter()`, or if the library allows this, write the output directly to the writer.

Jackson for example has `writeValue(writer, object)`. So in a servlet:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), yourData);

response.setContentType("application/json");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this example for getting it right :-

first pass name and age to onclick event through getUserDetails() method in js file from jsp then

```
  function getUserDetails() {      
       var name = document.getElementById('name');      
       var age = document.getElementById('age');

       // alert("hi " + name.value);
   $.getJSON("../webresources/myresource",
           {
                    name: name.value,
                    age: age.value
                },
                function(json) {

                    alert("name is= "+json.name+ " and age is ="+json.age);

                });
   }
```

and in servlet it should be like below :-

```
public class MyResource {

  @GET
  @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
  public Response getIt(
        @QueryParam("name") String name,
        @QueryParam("age") String age) {

    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName(name);
    person.setAge(Integer.parseInt(age));

//  Person persons = personService.findPerson(person);
    String temp1 = person.getName();
    int temp = person.getAge();
    String temp2 = Integer.toString(temp);

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    buffer.append(" { 'name':'");
    buffer.append(temp1);
    buffer.append(" ','age': ");
    buffer.append(temp2);
    buffer.append(" } ");
    String json = buffer.toString();

        // for example constructed string looks like
      // String json = "{'name':'ravi','age':21}";

    return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use request.getParameterMap() and display all the request parameters. You may find your desired parameter there.